# Mysqli to php to c#

Tags: c#, php, mysql, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array

So I have a list in c# that's being converted to a string, which is then converted to a 2-dimensional array in PHP, which is then sent to MySQL database. Now how do I go about reversing this, whereby I can download from the database to PHP than to c# list.

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure if I need to download the data back to an array in PHP or if I should download it as a string and break it up into a list in c#?

**This is my c# code:**

```
public List<Ship> shipList = new List<Ship>();
string shipListString = "";
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("username", username);
form.AddField("shipcount", ShipInventory.Count);  
for (int i = 0; i < shipList.Count; i++)
{        
    shipListString = shipListString + " " + shipList[i].id + " '" + shipList[i].username + "' '" + shipList[i].name + "' " + shipList[i].power +
             "zzz";// + ShipInventory[i];            
}
form.AddField("shipinventory", shipListString);
WWW www = new WWW("x.x.x.x/savedata.php", form);
yield return www;
```

**And this is my php:**

```
$shiparraytobesplit = $_POST["shipinventory"];
$ships =  explode("zzz", $shiparraytobesplit);
unset($ships[count($ships)-1]);

$shipinfo = array_map(function($ship) {
    $tempshipinfo = explode(" ", $ship);
    $ship_assoc = [
        "id" => $tempshipinfo[1],
        "name" => $tempshipinfo[2],
        "username" => $tempshipinfo[3],
        "hp" => $tempshipinfo[4]
    ];
    return $ship_assoc;
}, $ships);

$sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO shipinventory (shipid,shipname,username,shippower) VALUES (%s)', implode(',',array_values($shipinfo[$i])));

if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    echo("error description: " . mysqli_error($con));       
}
```

This is working well to upload my c# list into the database, but I'm not sure what's the best way to download it from the database back to a c# list. Any advice would be awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to make it work but I imagine there are better methods so please share! Thanks:

C# Script:

```
WWW www = new WWW("x.x.x.x/loaddata.php");
        yield return www;
        stringFromPHP = www.text;

        char[] delimiterENTER = new char[] {'\n' };
        char[] delimiterSPACE = new char[] { ' ' };
        shipStringArray = stringFromPHP.Split(delimiterENTER, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);        
        shipList.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < shipStringArray.Count(); i++)
        {
            string[] shipInfo = shipStringArray[i].Split(delimiterSPACE);                    
            shipList.Add(new Ship(Int32.Parse(shipInfo[0]), shipInfo[1], shipInfo[2], Int32.Parse(shipInfo[3]), shipStringArray[i]));            
        }
```

and php:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT shipid, username, shipname, shippower FROM shipinventory";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $stringtoexplodeincsharp  printf ("%s %s %s %s\n",(int) $row["shipid"], $row["username"], $row["shipname"],(int) $row["shippower"]);
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($con);
```